# How to have less explicit generic type parameters than total generic type parameters

Tags: generics, f#

I can recall having seen mentions of a way or "hack" in F# to have less explicit generic type parameters than the total number of generic type parameters, but I am unable to find any information on this.

I have tried doing this using a generic type (with all of the generic parameters and constraints) that has a static method with only the explicit parameters I want the user to specify.

Here is a simplified example that doesn't work:

```
type CreateBAndInvokeFoo< ^a, ^b when
                          ^a : (static member CreateB: unit -> ^b)
                          and ^b : (member Foo: unit -> unit)> =

  static member inline RunUsing< ^a> () : unit =
    let b = (^a: (static member CreateB: unit -> ^b) ())
    (^b: (member Foo: unit -> unit) b)



type FooB () =
  member _.Foo (s: string) = ()

type FooA =
  static member CreateB () = FooB()



CreateBAndInvokeFoo.RunUsing<FooA> ()
```

This fails with the following error on the last line:

> FS0071: Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'obj' for a type inference variable. The type 'obj' does not support the operator 'CreateB' Consider adding further type constraints

According to a comment below, this is because only functions (not types) support SRTP.

How can I make an API where the user explicitly specifies only a subset of the of generic types? (Without using `<_, _, _, _, _>`, because I have very many generic type parameters in my real-world use case.)

Comment: Types cannot have SRTPs, only functions can

Comment: Thanks! 1) Do you have a source for this where I can read more? 2) If you know any other way to accomplish having less explicit type parameters than total type parameters (the main question here), feel free to add an answer.